# Is there a way to program Conway's Game of Life with only one array

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I have written a program in C which implements Conway's Game of Life.

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char field[20][20] = {0}; //game field
    char cpy[20][20] = {0}; //copy of game field
    int gens;   //number of generations
    scanf("%d", &gens);//input by user
    while(1){   //runs till 'break;'
        char c;
        scanf(" %c", &c); //read next char
        if(c == 'a'){//break at char 'e'
            int i,j;
            scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);//scan coordinates
            field[j][i] = 1;    //setting cell to state alive
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    //calculate and print generations
    for(int i = 0; i <= gens; i++){
        printf("-- Generation: %d\n",i);
        //iterating over each cell
        for(int k = 0; k < 20;k++){
            for(int l = 0; l < 20; l++){
                //print current generation
                if(field[k][l] == 1){
                    printf("%c",'#');//alive
                }else{
                    printf("%c",'.');//dead
                }
                
                //counting neighbors of field[k][l]
                int neighbors = 0;
                for(int y = -1; y < 2; y++){
                    for(int x = -1; x < 2; x++){
                        if(!(x == 0 && y == 0)){
                            if( k + y < 20 &&
                                k + y >= 0  &&
                                l + x < 20 &&
                                l + x >= 0){
                                    if(field[k+y][l+x] == 1){
                                        neighbors++;
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
//rules
//Any live cell with two or three live neighbours survives.
//Any dead cell with three live neighbours becomes a live cell.
//All other live cells die in the next generation. Similarly, all other dead cells stay dead.
                if(field[k][l] == 1 &&
                   (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3)){
                    cpy[k][l] = 1;       
                }else if(field[k][l] == 0 &&
                   neighbors == 3){
                    cpy[k][l] = 1;       
                }else if(field[k][l] == 1){
                    cpy[k][l] = 0;
                }
                
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        
        //setting gamefield to new generation
        for(int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < 20; b++){
                field[a][b] = cpy[a][b];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The user Input looks like that

```
3
a 9 9
a 9 10
a 9 11
e
```

The first number indicates how many generations are to be simulated. After that, the user can set individual cells to 1 by entering the character `a`, followed by the `x` and `y` coordinates of the cell. To determine the end of the input, the user enters the character `e`.

As you can see there are 2 arrays in my code one represents the current generation the second represents the next generation.

Just because it interests me, is there a way to implement the whole thing so that you only need one array?

Comment: Sure. Think about the type you use for each individual cell. How many bits do you actually use? Just use the 2nd bit for the next generation, and when you have calculated all fields, bitshift the old value from all fields.

Comment: Sure. Copy the row you are working on to a temporary row before you start working on it, and do the update in place. A naive approach would require two temporary rows, but actually you can cut that down to one complete row (for the next iteration) and a couple of temporary elements. It's a bit more bookkeeping but a lot less storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing the original fields, e.g. `field[k][l] == 1` you could check it like this: `(field[k][l] & 1) == 1`.
Now you are only checking the one-bit of each field.

Then instead of setting a value in the copy like you do (`cpy[k][l] = 1`) you would do `field[k][l] |= (1 << 1)` a.k.a. set the second bit while merging it with the value of the first bit.

Finally, you would iterate over all fields again, and perform `field[k][l] >>= 1`. All the second bits are shifted right, all the first bits are forgotten.

```
//setting gamefield to new generation
for(int a = 0; a < 20; a++){
    for(int b = 0; b < 20; b++){
        field[a][b] >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The counting of neighbors can be combined: each cell adds the count of its 4 upstream neighbors plus the 4 downstream neighbors - and when you count the downsream ones, you add their neighbor count.

```
  --->

|  u u u
|  u * d
|  d d d 
v
```

So only one array is needed, but a second field:

```
struct onecell {
    int alive;
    int neibs;
} **cells;
```

The function:

```
void do_row(struct onecell *row, struct onecell *rlow) {

    int j;
    int nbs;
    struct onecell *c, *n1;

    for (j = 1; j <= COLSDISP; j++) {

        c  =  &row[ j ]; 
        n1 =  &row[j+1];        // same row, to the right

        nbs = c->neibs + n1->alive;                                   // add the 4 neighbors to the right and below
        nbs += rlow[ j ].alive + rlow[j+1].alive + rlow[j-1].alive;

        if (c->alive) {

            n1->neibs++;                // tell downstream that we are alive  
            rlow[ j ].neibs++; 
            rlow[j+1].neibs++;
            rlow[j-1].neibs++;

            if (nbs < 2 || nbs > 3)
                c->alive = 0;

        } else
            if (nbs == 3)
                c->alive = 1;

        c->neibs = 0;                    // reset
    }
}
```

The border rows have to be handled separately; with multithreading it looks like this:

```
while (loops++ < 1000) {

        for (i = CHUNK; i <= ROWSDISP; i += CHUNK)
             prepare_bottomrow(cells[i], cells[i+1]);

        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(THREADS)

        for (i = 1; i <= ROWSDISP; i++)
            if (i % CHUNK != 0)
                do_row(cells[i], cells[i+1]);
            else
                do_bottomrow(cells[i]);

        // print_matrix();
        // usleep(40000); 

    }
```

The `...bottomrow()` do each half of what `do_row()` does; `prepare_bottomrow()` is outside the `parallel`, because it crosses a `CHUNK`. But even without `omp parallel` there would be one bottom row.

The rows, threads and chunksize have to be divisible e.g. 200 rows, 4 threads and CHUNK=50.

This algotithm is fast. `rlow[j].neibs` and `rlow[j].alive` are side by side.